# Create a link from a polygon on a world map

Tags: javascript, html, interactive, polygons

I'm currently using the 'pooch interactive globe' js files from here: http://blueshirt.com/pooch/examples/interactive-globe.html

How would I be able to make each individual country (polygon) a clickable link to a new html?